# ?_format=json does not produce JSON for files, REST

Tags: files

I am using Drupal 9.3 with REST UI, RESTful Web Services, and Serialization enabled.
For the REST UI, I have the following configuration for files:

Methods:
GET, POST, DELETE, PATCH

Accepted request formats: json, xml

Authentication providers: cookie,

but when I try to get a json for a file (by appending `?_format=json` to the url), I just get the file itself back (in other words the page is the same as without `?_format=json`). This only happens for files, both media and nodes generate the json as usual.

Has anybody experienced this or knows how to fix it?

Comment: For example, when I have some media, at say `baseurl/media/1`, I can get a json by changing the url to `baseurl/media/1?_format=json`, similarly with nodes, `baseurl/node/1?_format=json`, I would like to do the same thing with files like `baseurl/sites/default/files/2021-06/test_0.txt`

Answer (score 1):

This is because Drupal delivers the file from filesystem without any processing.

If you want a file delivered as JSON (whatever that means). You need a controller that loads the file, then does a json_decode on the content and returns the result as Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse.

And you also need a route for that controller method.

Comment: I quite new to Drupal, could you provide some guidance on how to go about doing that (creating a controller and route)

Comment: You can find all of this, including code examples at drupal.org, i.e. here: https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/routing-system/introductory-drupal-8-routes-and-controllers-example

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add `?_format=json` to a file url at `www.example.com/sites/default/files` because that is just the directory of site files.

So why does Drupal give you json when you add `?_format=json` to `www.example.com/node/123?_format=json` or `www.example.com/media/123?_format=json`?  That's because these are [entities](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/entity-api/introduction-to-entity-api-in-drupal-8).

So, how can you use `?_format=json` with files?  You'll need to use entities.

The easiest way to do this is with the Media module, which is built into core.

To try this out:

1. Install the media module.
2. Go to `/admin/structure/media`.

By default, some basic media types will be created (audio, document, image, remote video, and video).

Check out the **Doument** media type as it is a good example of using files.

You can also easily create new media types for your specific use case.

Then you can use `?_format=json` on the media URLs that you create.

The downside of this approach is that you still can't get the json from the file directory path; you will have to use the media entity url instead.

To set the media entity urls automatically based on a pattern, you can use [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto).